# Spawn memory leak issue

Tags: node.js, memory, spawn

I am not sure how I go about fixing this issue, for some reason, just every now and again my nodeJS app seems to fire a spawn error which I can't figure out how to fix or resolve.

```
Error: spawn ENOMEM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:406:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:237:17)
    at exec (child_process.js:158:25)
    at CheckIP (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/app.js:57:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:71:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/(PATH)/(APPNAME)/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

I am wondering is it possible to have a script that watches for this error and if it happens run:

```
systemctl stop  APPNAME
systemctl start  APPNAME
```

I know that does not fix the problem but until I can work out what the issue is I need a temp solution.

from everything I am reading seems it that the spawn is a memory thing? Not 100% sure, if that is the case could I have a script that releases memory as the app continues to run?Swap

Comment: When you get that error, then run some diagnostics to see what is using the memory on your system.  My wild guess (since you show no relevant code) would be some spawned child processes that did not complete and you build them up until you run out of memory.

Comment: When you get that error, you could just kill your own process and be running it under nodemon or forever or something like that which would automatically restart it.  No need for some external watcher to see that error since you encounter it yourself in your program, you can just call `process.exit()` to shut down and let the process monitor you already have restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the Memory. More precisely  it is linked with Swap Memory.

If you want to automatically restart your node app. You can run it with help of PM2 and configure it's restart [strategies](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/)

If you are using Ubantu and want to update swap size you can follow instructions mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)